# Delete row phpexcel

Tags: php, regex, phpexcel

I want to load my file.xls and check if my elements contains the character `^`; then, I want to remove it.

Here my code so far:

```
$objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load("trainbayes.xlsx");
foreach ($objPHPExcel->getWorksheetIterator() as $worksheet){
$column = 'C';
$lastRow = $worksheet->getHighestRow();
  for ($row = 2; $row <= $lastRow; $row++) {    
      $cell = $worksheet->getCell($column.$row);
      if (preg_match("/([\^])/",$cell)){
          $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->removeRow($row,$row);
      }
   }
}
```

But it didn't work. Can you help me? Thank you :)

Comment: Are you sure you are passing right parameters to `removeRow()`?

Comment: @revo not sure about that :(

Comment: Try and change `$cell = $worksheet->getCell($column.$row);` to `$cell = $worksheet->getCell($column.$row)->getValue();`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$cell = $worksheet->getCell($column.$row);
```

Returns a Cell **object** and assigns it to `$cell`; you are then treating that cell object as though it was a string in your `preg_match()` call.

Surely you should be checking the **value** of the cell

```
$cell = $worksheet->getCell($column.$row)->getValue();
```

---

Additionally,

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->removeRow($row,$row);
```

Do you really mean to pass `$row` twice? Second argument is the number of rows to delete, first argument is the row number to start deleting, so if you pass `$row` is `5`, then PHPExcel will delete 5 rows, starting at row number 5.

Surely you mean

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->removeRow($row, 1);
```

or simply

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->removeRow($row);
```